# Why angle and solid angle not included in fundamental physical quantity?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units

So I recently studied about physical quantities.
I doubt what **actually** Fundamental physical quantities is??

Book simply says it as 'quanties which doesn't depend on other physical quantities"
What actually "fundamental" means here??

Do angle depend on any physical quantity?

And why Angle and solid angle are having separate group.
Why are they not **Fundamental physical quantity**?

Comment: Could you provide the book name and authors?

Comment: There are many....but being in class 11 i am studying NCERT Physics part 1 Chapter 1. You can download it from net. Its a open source being a Gov. Authorised book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to look at physical quantities is in terms of how they are measured. For that, it is best to consider their definitions as provided by the [BIPM](https://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units) (the organization that maintains the international system of measurements --- the SI units). They refer to it as "the recommended practical system of units of measurement." In other words, they don't talk about "fundamental units," nor do they imply that it is only way to do it.

According to the SI system, there are 7 *base* units (as opposed to *fundamental* units) in terms of which all other units can be defined. Therefore, the "fundamental physical quantities" are simply those that have been found to be convenient to use for the definition of all other quantities and can be measured in such a way that one can specify their units as precisely as currently possible.

About angles, they are given as a distance divided by a distance, and therefore are dimensionless. However, due to the context in which they appear, it is convenient to give them a separate unit. The same applies for solid angles.

Comment: Is there any relation between plane and solid angle. For ex . What i thought(may be wrong) was that suppose i take y radian plane angle and  similarly i take a poing inside a ball and from that point i draw Y radian in all 3D directions.....appears like a cone hope u can imagine , So suppose that measure of solid angle equal to X steradian. So does that have some relation with Y radian??? Or not?hope u get my point?  "Like X steradian can be form when we take Y radian in all 3D direction"?? Something like this concept??? Or does radian and steradian has NO connection?

Comment: No, angles and solid angles can appear in different contexts. For that reason, I don't think there exists a general relationship that would be valid in all situations.